# How to prevent app from closing on background?

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

Every android app I build on kivy with buildozer restarts itself after being in the background. Even if I slide down the notifications when on the app the app restarts.

I tried finding documentation about this issue but didn't find anything.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
''')


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

This is the app I'm trying to run, with a default buildozer.spec only adding opencv for the camera.

Comment: Try writing `def on_pause(self): return True` in your TestCamera class. That shouldn't be necessary though. More likely, are you pressing the back button to exit the app? By default this may close it. Does pressing the app drawer or home buttons do the same thing?

Comment: That was it, very strange. I was not pressing the back button, anything I did outside the app closed it, but now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
''')


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()

    def on_pause(self): 
        return True


TestCamera().run()
```

Changing the on_pause method solves it.

Comment: on_pause should return True by default on recent Kivy versions, which is why I didn't expect it to work. Might be worth checking everything is up to date.